# How to login directly in integration tests in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

SessionController action ends in `redirect_to root_path`.

Doing this

```
def sign_in(user)
  visit new_session_path
  fill_in "Username or email", with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: 'please'
  click_button "Sign in"
  expect(page).to have_content "Sign out"
end
```

gives correct redirection:

```
Redirected to http://www.example.com/
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-28 01:08:13 -0800
Processing by Homepages::SponsorsController#index as HTML
...
```

But this

```
def sign_in(user)
  page.driver.post session_path,
    'session[credential]' => user.email,
    'session[password]' => 'please'
end
```

Doesn't redirect correctly:

```
Redirected to http://www.example.com/
Completed 302 Found in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the `page.driver` with `Capybara.current_session.driver`:

```
def sign_in(user)
  driver = Capybara.current_session.driver
  driver.submit :post, session_path,
    'session[credential]' => user.email,
    'session[password]' => 'please'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In every form generated by the `form_for` helper method, there is a hidden field named `authenticity_token` that contains a token used to prevent XSS attacks.

I suspect this could be the reason you're having problems posting directly to this controller.